# How to get system() to use wildcard

Tags: c, beagleboneblack

I'm using ubuntu. I tried to use the system() function with a wild card and every time I run the function, it takes * as a literal. The command i'm using within system is echo. It looks like this.

```
system("echo cape-bone-iio > /sys/devices/bone_capmgr.*/slots)
```

I tried sperating it and many other things but I cannot make this wild card work. It returns an error:

```
Sh: 1: cannot create /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots
```

It works when I run it through the terminal but not from the program

I have a workaround and it just cycles through number 0 through 99 but it takes up much more resources than I would like. I know its not safe to use the system command but i'm strictly using for the beaglebone system.

Comment: Are you sure it works from the terminal? Looks like an `ambiguous redirect` to me.

Comment: Yes. No error and when I check the file it is all there

Comment: your going about this wrong, you should write directly to the `slots` file

Comment: This isnt a normal file, its system controlled but the problem would be identifying the number the goes where the wildcard is. That number can change depending on the boot order I believe

Comment: Does the slots file exist or does your command create it? Can it be guaranteed to exist?

Comment: Its exists before the command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/sys/devices/bone_capmgr.*/slots` globbing is expanded by the shell before running your `echo`. Read [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html). If it matches two files (e.g. with `*` being either `2` or `7`) your command is expanded as:

```
echo cape-bone-iio > \
  /sys/devices/bone_capmgr.2/slots /sys/devices/bone_capmgr.7/slots
```

and you see then that it is non-sense. (but it would make sense if `*` is expanded to one thing like `4`). If no file matches the globbing pattern your shell probably would create a file name with an `*` inside (and this triggers the `cannot create /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots` message).

You might run perhaps

```
for f in /sys/devices/bone_capmgr.*/slots ; do \
  echo cape-bone-iio > $f ; \
done
```

But I don't think that passing such a long string to `system` is always a good idea. You could do the `for` loop in your C program (using e.g. [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) + [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) on `/sys/devices/` ...) then you don't even need any  `system` (just some `fopen` +  `fprintf` +  `fclose` in your loop using `readdir`...). You could also use [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) or [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html).

<sup>You probably need to handle the case when no `/sys/devices/bone_capmgr.*/slots` file exists, e.g. because some hardware is missing or unconnected.</sup>

BTW, the shell invoked by [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) would scan the directories like `readdir`(or `glob` or `wordexp`) do, so coding that loop by hand avoids forking a shell and should run slightly faster.

You could also use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) but I believe it is too general for your needs. It scans recursively a file tree like the [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command does.

You could also use `snprintf` to generate a file name in a `for (ix=0; ix<100; x++)` loop and test its existence using [access(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html)

At last, you might perhaps query the existence of these devices thru `/proc/` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more, if it exposes something about your hardware). [udev(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udev.7.html) might also be relevant.

BTW try to [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) the shell interpreting your `echo` command in the terminal (or simply `strace /bin/sh -c "echo cape-bone-iio > /sys/devices/bone_capmgr.*/slots"`) to find out the [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) used by your shell.

There is nothing that the shell does that you cannot do with plain syscalls.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The problem is that I cannot directly write to the file from the program. There is only one file with that name but the number changes every boot.

Comment: But you can `readdir` the directory containing that file to find that file hence the number...

Comment: I would like to add the best solution was using glob in the c program. This made it so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using the `system` call then another alternative would be the `find` command:

```
system( "find /sys/devices/ -type d -name 'bone_capmgr.*'"
         " -exec sh -c 'echo cap-bone-iio > {}/slots' \;"  );
```

This would then prevent the ambiguous redirect error mentioned in the comments should there be more than one directory matching the glob pattern `bone_capmgr.*`.

I would however recommend taking the advice offered by Basile Starynkevitch.

Answer (score -1):

First of all I must say that you should write directly to the file rather than spawn a process to do it for you.

Having said that, you can do what you ask via 
`system("sh -c 'echo cape-bone-iio > /sys/devices/bone_capmgr.*/slots'")`

Comment: Useless since by definition `system` is forking a `/bin/sh -c` !